# can 'this' pointer be null in c++ class?

Tags: java, c++, jvm, metadata

There is a c++ code shown below:

```
class Metadata : public MetaspaceObj {
    void print_value_on_maybe_null(outputStream* st) const {
    if (this == NULL)
      st->print("NULL");
    else
      print_value_on(tty);
    }
}
```

I just wonder how could 'this' be NULL in a C++ object.Could be there a possibility?

The code above is excerpted from jdk8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/oops/metadata.hpp.

Comment: @BitNinja: I guess because this is from the JDK.

Comment: @nneonneo Is that ok? Because there's not java code here.

Comment: "this" is just passed around as an implicit  parameter, so yes, there's a few ways it could end up being null.

Comment: @Ben, can you give an example? i just can't imagine how it could

Comment: @JSlain Like the examples given below where the method is invoked on a null pointer. Or, if this is set to null inside the method.

Comment: @Ben Oh i just noticed all of this were still about C++. I couldn't figure out how this could happen in Java.

Comment: It can happen in java. If you set it to null yourself. In C++, you can call delete on the this pointer and then set it to null. I'm sure you could set "this" to null in java too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ you actually can dereference and call member functions on a `NULL` pointer.

Consider:

```
Metadata* pointer = nullptr;
pointer->print_value_on_maybe_null(...);
```

The code above is valid C++ code, it compiles fine. The problem with this is that it leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

Going back to the code in the question, I think there were, some time in the past, a bug somewhere that cause the member function to be called on a null pointer, and instead of trying to find and fix the root cause of the problem, the authors just added a check for `this == NULL`.

Comment: Alternately, since Java `null` objects are represented by NULL pointers in the JDK, this may be a misguided "optimization" to reduce the number of null checks required at call sites.

Comment: Quite misguided, as the compiler may very well decide to remove the check inside the method. Modern compilers are good at dead-code removal, and one particular case is removing code for a null-pointer check if the compiler can prove that pointer is never null. That's trivially true for `this`.

Comment: @MSalters I've tested this. In release mode, GCC indeed removes such checks, even they have side effects. MSVC meanwhile keeps them (by default).

Comment: @cz: I'm pretty sure that you didn't mean to say exactly that. GCC will not remove the side effects of the *check*. I.e. if the check is `if (volatile b= (this != nullptr); b)` then GCC will keep the side effects. Optimizations in general do not affect observable behavior including side effects (unless specifically allowed by the Standard).

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, it is not permitted to call a method on a null pointer; something like this is undefined behavior:

```
Metadata * foo = NULL;
foo->print_value_on_maybe_null(NULL);
```

So, a compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants in such a case.

But as long as the method is not virtual, typical compilers will not bother to include any check that `foo` is non-null, since there's no need for such a check. (With a virtual method, of course, it would have to examine `foo` to retrieve the vtable and call the appropriate version of the method.) So . . . yes, it's quite possible, but only if the calling code has a bug (or what many programmers would consider to be bug).

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined behaviour to call a method on a NULL instance.

That said, most compilers won't do anything strange if you do write the following:

```
Metadata *x = NULL;
x->print_value_on_maybe_null(&os);
```

but you are walking a bit of a fine line.